# Save textbox1 entry into xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Here is my code:

```
 static void main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load("data.XML");
        XmlNodeList userNodes = xmldoc.SelectNodes("data.XML");
        foreach (XmlNode userNode in userNodes) ;

    }

    private string id;
    private string APIkey;
    private string VCode;

    public string ID
    {
         get { return id; }
         set { id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); }
    }

    public string APIKEY
    {
        get { return APIkey; }
        set { APIkey = value; }
    }

    public string VCODE
    {
        get { return VCode; }
        set { VCode = value; }

    }

    public static void SaveData(object obj, string Filename)
    {

        XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Filename, true);
        sr.Serialize(writer, obj);
        writer.Close();

    }
}
```

Here is my button;

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    {
       try
    {


        APISAVE info = new APISAVE();
        info.APIKEY = txtAPI.Text;
        info.VCODE = txtVerC.Text;
        info.ID = info.ID;
        APISAVE.SaveData(info, "data.XML");

    }

    catch (Exception ex)

    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

ok what i want to do is add what i type in the text boxes to go into the XML file BUT when i do it again it'll add it to the XML not overwrite it.

i've been googling for awhile and reading lots of bits and it's just not making any sense, i've tried. im now asking for a good hearted soul to please explain to me in baby language were it's all going wrong.

EDIT

XML OUTPUT;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Serialization xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<ID>91bb44be-d55e-40f6-83f7-8fb43d0a7321</ID>
<APIKEY>12</APIKEY>
<VCODE>12</VCODE>
</Serialization><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Serialization xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<ID>c2a45a36-e7c8-4ac5-a37c-87c452db5807</ID>
<APIKEY>123</APIKEY>
<VCODE>123</VCODE>
 </Serialization>
```

Another Edit:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using No_IdeaV2.API_Key_Window;
using System.IO;

namespace No_IdeaV2.API_Key_Window
{
public partial class UCAPIn : Form
{        
    public UCAPIn()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender,  ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void whatAmIDoingToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public List<Serialization> list = null;
    private void UCAPIn_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        list = new List<Serialization>();
        var doc = XDocument.Load("data.XML");

        foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("Serialization"))
        {
            list.Add(new Serialization()
            { ID = element.Element("ID").Value, APIKEY = element.Element("APIKEY").Value, VCODE = element.Element("VCODE").Value });
        }
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            try
            {
                Serialization info = new Serialization();
                info.APIKEY = txtAPI.Text;
                info.VCODE = txtVerC.Text;
                info.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                list.Add(info);
                Serialization.SaveData(list, "data.XML");

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void whatIsThisToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }





        public class Serialization
    {
        private string id;
        private string APIkey;
        private string VCode;

        public string ID
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        public string APIKEY
        {
            get { return APIkey; }
            set { APIkey = value; }
        }

        public string VCODE
        {
            get { return VCode; }
            set { VCode = value; }

        }

        public static void SaveData(List<Serialization> list, string      Filename)
        {
            XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(list.GetType());
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Filename, true);
            sr.Serialize(writer, list);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: my `System.IO.File.Delete()` the file before writing to it?

Comment: Please show an example of the XML structure with one and multiple records in it.

Comment: You have something wrong with `ID` (perhaps it should be `info.ID = txtID.Text` ?). And the tip: make `SaveData` non-static, then you don't need `obj` to pass (it will be instance, use `this` in place of `obj`).

Comment: Yeah that's not valid XML.

Comment: indeed, the ID if fine since i want to use the data put in later so i need something to seperate them IE the randomly generated ID numbers.

Comment: `new StreamWriter(Filename, true);` - _true_ to append data to the file; _false_ to overwrite the file.

Comment: indeed it does append it but writes the whole thing again including the root elements, im having trouble adding it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my full code and this works:

```
namespace WinForms_CSharp
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public  List<APISAVE> list = null;
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            list = new List<APISAVE>();
            if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "\\data.xml"))
            {
                var doc = XDocument.Load("data.XML");

                foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("APISAVE"))
                {
                    list.Add(new APISAVE() { ID = element.Element("ID").Value, APIKEY = element.Element("APIKEY").Value, VCODE = element.Element("VCODE").Value });
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                APISAVE info = new APISAVE();
                info.APIKEY = txtAPI.Text;
                info.VCODE = txtVerC.Text;
                info.ID = info.ID;
                list.Add(info);
                APISAVE.SaveData(list, "data.XML");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }       
    } // end of Form2 class

    public class APISAVE
    {
        private string id;
        private string APIkey;
        private string VCode;

        public string ID
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); }
        }

        public string APIKEY
        {
            get { return APIkey; }
            set { APIkey = value; }
        }

        public string VCODE
        {
            get { return VCode; }
            set { VCode = value; }

        }

        public static void SaveData(List<APISAVE> list, string Filename)
        {
            File.Delete(Filename);
            XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(list.GetType());
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Filename, true);
            sr.Serialize(writer, list);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"what i type in the text boxes to go into the XML file BUT when i do it again it'll add it to the XML not overwrite it."_

Comment: If you are just overwriting every time, why not just re-create every time with the new data?

Comment: nah this just pretty much overrides whats there, i want to add to it, not delete the data thats already there.

Comment: "what i want to do is add what i type in the text boxes to go into the XML file BUT when i do it again it'll add it to the XML not overwrite it"    confilicting statements                                                                             "nah this just pretty much overrides whats there, i want to add to it"

Comment: @thewisegod no, that does not contradict. OP wants to add instead of overwrite, though phrased quite poorly indeed.

Comment: pish posh, your right i haven't wrote it very well.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: Root element is missing.

Comment: Delete your xml document. The structure of my document looks like this and it was created by my code.                                                                       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<ArrayOfAPISAVE xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


-<APISAVE>

<ID>c1d5d856-d359-45a8-8622-c8582ff954c0</ID>

<APIKEY>ttttt</APIKEY>

<VCODE>ttttt</VCODE>

</APISAVE>


-<APISAVE>

<ID>245b849c-e45a-4bf3-af59-f7b231372e58</ID>

<APIKEY>hhh</APIKEY>

<VCODE>hhh</VCODE>

</APISAVE>

</ArrayOfAPISAVE>

Comment: So this gives you the xml exception?

Comment: when i delete the XML it says i need it and when i put a blank data.XML in the location it wants it says "Additional information: Root element is missing.". what happends when you open your XML in firefox? does it open ok?

Comment: I removed File.Delete(Filename); before saving the list. Check my updated answer. So it was adding multiple roots and doubling the xml.

Comment: it works! you sir are fantastic !! it looks like i needed a correctly formatted XML to start with since this doesnt create it from scratch. just means when this gets into trials i'll have to include a XML with a "pilot data" so it doesnt fall over. Can i ask a big question because i feel that i've kinda just copied and pasted this.. can you explain what each section is / does? so i learn something from this lol (thanks in advance)

Comment: Even when I delete the data.xml document, my code creates it. Glad you got it solved, but maybe keep looking and trying to figure out why you can't start without an xml document. Could you please upvote and mark as answered.

Comment: yeah i sure will, glad i joined this site now :) tried a different site for coding to ask for help the other week and just got flamed and got called a "goobak" whatever that is. once again thanks a million

Comment: just a FYI this is the part im getting an error "var doc = XDocument.Load("data.XML");"

Comment: OK, I modified once more. Notice I check to see if the File.Exists before I try to load it.

Comment: 1 slight bug on this i found! works great when it's open but when i reopen the program it removes all the data in the XML and puts in the new data instead of keeping whats already there.

Comment: OK. I made one more modification to the code. Notice the "Application.StartupPath" in the if statement.

Comment: forgot to comment back seems like it solved it self.. dunno how it's working now though and i cant see any adjustments made.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to load, deserialize, add, serialize and write the file. You could load the XML, serialize in-memory and inject the serialized objects into the XML, but that's less trivial and I'll let you figure that out on your own.

So create an XML as you like:

```
<RootObject>
    <NestedObject>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <VCODE>ABC123</VCODE>
        <APIKEY>xyz789</APIKEY>
    </NestedObject>
    <NestedObject>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <VCODE>ABC456</VCODE>
        <APIKEY>xyz456</APIKEY>
    </NestedObject>
</RootObject>
```

Paste this into Visual Studio as new classes (Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML As Classes) and use those in your (de)serialization code:

```
public RootObject LoadData(string filename)
{
    using (XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootObject)))
    {
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
        return (RootObject)sr.Deserialize(writer, obj);
    }
}
public RootObject SaveData(string filename, RootObject objectToSerialize)
{
    using (XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootObject)))
    {
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
        sr.Serialize(writer, objectToSerialize);
    }
}
```

Then you can load or create, and then modify the RootObject instance:

```
// Load or instantiate

string xmlFileName = "yourfilename.xml";    
RootObject rootObject;

if (File.Exists(xmlFileName))
{
    rootObject = LoadData(xmlFileName);
}
else
{
    rootObject = new RootObject
    {
        NestedObject = new RootObjectNestedObject[]         
    };
}

// Modify

var nestedObjects = new List<RootObjectNestedObject>(rootObject.NestedObject);

nestedObjects.Add(new RootObjectNestedObject
{
    ID = 42,
    VCODE = "foo",
    APIKEY = "bar"
});

// Save
rootObject.NestedObject = nestedObjects.ToArray();

SaveData(xmlFileName, rootObject);
```

Comment: even thou the other method worked, im going to give this one ago as well