# XML being overwirtten then program is re-opened

Tags: c#

so here it is my code.

```
public List<Serialization> list = null;
private void UCAPIn_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    list = new List<Serialization>();

    if (File.Exists("date.XML"))

    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("data.XML");


        foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("Serialization"))
        {

            list.Add(new Serialization()
            { ID = element.Element("ID").Value,
                APIKEY = element.Element("APIKEY").Value,
                VCODE = element.Element("VCODE").Value });
        }
    }
}

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        try
        {
            Serialization info = new Serialization();                    
            info.APIKEY = txtAPI.Text;
            info.VCODE = txtVerC.Text;
            info.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();                                   
            list.Add(info);                    
            Serialization.SaveData(list, "data.XML");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}

private void whatIsThisToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
// end of UCAPIn

public class Serialization
{
    private string id;
    private string APIkey;
    private string VCode;

    public string ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public string APIKEY
    {
        get { return APIkey; }
        set { APIkey = value; }
    }

    public string VCODE
    {
        get { return VCode; }
        set { VCode = value; }
    }

    public static void SaveData(List<Serialization> list, string Filename)
    {

        File.Delete(Filename);
        XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(list.GetType());                    
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Filename, true);            
        sr.Serialize(writer, list); 
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

it create my XML and adds to it (multiple entries) but when i close the program and reopen it add some more data in the older data is gone, overwritten by the new.

Can anyone help me with this one?

(thanks in advance)

XML Sample (when File.Delete(Filename); is removed.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfSerialization xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Serialization>
        <ID>f2310827-93d0-42aa-9bfe-32624ee5f97b</ID>
        <APIKEY>1234</APIKEY>
        <VCODE>1234</VCODE>
    </Serialization>
</ArrayOfSerialization>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfSerialization xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Serialization>
        <ID>df354c83-1ae2-4cfc-b802-c9682f24f3f6</ID>
        <APIKEY>123</APIKEY>
        <VCODE>123</VCODE>
    </Serialization>
</ArrayOfSerialization>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfSerialization xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Serialization>
        <ID>df354c83-1ae2-4cfc-b802-c9682f24f3f6</ID>
        <APIKEY>123</APIKEY>
        <VCODE>123</VCODE>
    </Serialization>
    <Serialization>
        <ID>a8f6737e-6c08-4e7a-b041-c16b502d4a60</ID>
        <APIKEY>1234</APIKEY>
        <VCODE>1234</VCODE>
    </Serialization>
</ArrayOfSerialization>
```

Comment: Where are you calling UCAPIn_Load()? is it form load event?

Comment: You test the existence of a file named date.xml and then Load a file named data.xml so it won't never be loaded and the data is lost at first rewrite.

Comment: well ! good question im not.. the only place i can trace it to is the deisgner.cs with this "            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.UCAPIn_Load);" if i remove it then it falls over.

Comment: you have to change this to check for data.xml  "if (File.Exists("date.XML"))"

Comment: Said so can I ask you why do you use XDocument and write a lot of code instead of defining a class and using Xml Serialization that reads and writes your files directly into your class?

Comment: well im new to all this codin business so this is a learning curve, no specific reason for it.

Comment: Well, your `SaveData()` function calls `File.Delete()` at the start, so no wonder your old data is gone? Or do I just not understand the problem?

Comment: no your right, i've removed / moved this about and the get the following problem. it doesnt format well.

Comment: It is hard to follow your code (too many cases of default names), but any system that mixes up different ways of operating on the XML (eg. LINQ to XML and XML Serialisation) is going to have problems.

Comment: provide sample  XML data.

Comment: @Sabrina_cs because it is easy create a specific document structure with LINQ to XML (or Xml Document or Xml Writer, ...) but not with XML Serialisation except when internal data structures are very similar (often but certainly not always the case). And of course if XML Serialisation does not immediately work debugging it is much harder.

Comment: added my XML example.

Comment: @Sabrina_cs [I suggested that on their previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32763209/save-textbox1-entry-into-xml), but they chose to take this approach. The posted XML, as in the previous question, is not valid XML. It has multiple root elements.

Comment: yep that was my XML before and the modthode i chose may not be the best but it worked till i found this slight bug :)

Comment: what the actual F*** for some unknown reason it's working perfectly... but i can't see any changes made.

Comment: well my spelling seems to be the main issue here. wow. cheers all :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this sample code helps you.

I'm using the same property class that you are using "Serialization"

For Deserialization use this method:

```
public List<Serialization> XMLDeserialize()
{
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Serialization>));
    TextReader reader = new StreamReader(xmlPath);
    var XMLDeserialize = (List<Serialization>) deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
    reader.Dispose();
    return XMLDeserialize;
}
```

To update the xml file use this function:

```
public void UpdateXMLSerialize(List<Serialization> objXmlData)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Serialization>));
    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(xmlPath))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, objXmlData);
    }
}
```

To add new data in xml on click event:

```
private void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Serialization> list = new List<Serialization>();

    if (File.Exists(xmlPath))
    {
        list = XMLDeserialize();

        Serialization obj = new Serialization() { ID = "NewData", APIKEY = "NewAPIKey", VCODE = "NewVCode" };
        list.Add(obj);
        UpdateXMLSerialize(list);              
    }
}
```